# Widget creation page

Tags: javascript, widget

In facebook we have functionality for widget creation like the like box,activity feed,through input like how the width should be or how the height should need a reference to create similar  kind of page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a little more punctuation would be appreciated, it's not obvious what you're actually asking for.

Secondly, I don't think you'll find a reference or anything like that easily anywhere. What you're talking about is a highly customized system Facebook has spent a lot of time and resources designing and implementing. You'll hardly find a tutorial for that sort of thing. It's an amalgamation of many different common and some maybe not so common techniques and design patterns. If you have no idea where to even start building something like that, don't. Build a few small systems that do some small part: a dropdown menu, an AJAX-driven page, an auto-suggestion search box, tabs, etc. pp. When you understand enough about the individual parts, you can start putting them together in something as complex as Facebook.